# whenever I want to install any package or upgrade this issue occurs please help me I searched on google chatgpt but did not resolve

Tags: command-line, upgrade, software-installation, wps-office

whenever I want to install any package or upgrade this issue occurs please help me I searched on google chatgpt but did not resolve please help me I searched on google chatgpt but did not resolve [In this picture I update command worded but upgrade command did not worked same for other packages[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EyQ7.png) I had uninstalled wps-office and related files

Answer (score 1):

The error message strongly suggests that you tried to uninstall wps-office in some unusual manner instead of using your package manager...and that you were only partially successful.

Lesson Learned: ALWAYS use the package manager to install and remove software packages. NEVER use `rm` or other tools to remove package-manager-placed files.

Going forward, you have two options.

1. You can do what the error message says and make wps-office available for reinstall. Then reinstall it. Then uninstall it properly. This is preferable and clean.
2. You can try forcing apt. Don't do this lightly.

   `sudo apt --force remove wps-office`

   If that fails, you can use the nuclear option below. **WARNING**: We call it the 'nuclear option' because it's the last resort and it's *powerful*. Injudicious use may damage your system.

   `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq wps-office`

   That command will cause the package manager to simply forget about some files that might still be on your system. It will be up to you to locate and remove those forgotten files, if any. That's not easy.

Answer (score 0):

First step is to update your repositories:

```
sudo apt update
```

After that, install all updatable software with:

```
sudo apt upgrade
```

Now your system should be ok. Then try to install VLC.

Background: Your "upgrade" won't help, because you have old repository data. "Update" will load the new catalog from where you could install. Then your "upgrade" will install the newest versions of libraries and applications

If you still got problems with WPS Office, you need to remove it:

```
sudo apt purge wps-office
```